# Qt Creator в OS X Yosemite нету комплектов для Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Возникла проблема на OSX, в Qt Creator нету комплектов для Qt Designer, ставил qt creator из brew
[image: a busy cat]
![two muppets][1]

Comment: Ставьте официальный с сайта qt.io

Comment: Я бы поставил, но требует xcode 8 который как я понял только для El Capitan и выше, а я по некоторым причинам не могу обновить Yosemite до El Capitan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все же обновил систему, Qt Designer завелся